# How to name an array's boxes

Tags: java, arrays

So I was looking to change and see if I can swap the elements in an array which I did correctly in the code linked. (I just swapped 1st and 3rd element for the hell of it) But I was wondering how I can get the user to pick which ones to swap. But to do this I'm assuming you need to name each individual box(es). I'm not quite sure how you would do that though. Sorry in advance for the messy code I space it out a lot because I'm new to coding and it helps me read it and understand it better.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class caniremember
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //String userInputs[] = {"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eigth", "ninth", "tenth", };

        int userInputs [] = new int[10];
        
        System.out.println("Let me sway deez things re quick brudda! ;)");
        System.out.println("Gimmie da freaking things brudda");

        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("First int PLEASE PERSON");
            userInputs[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here is your array");
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(userInputs[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Now im going to swap the first and third");

        int h = userInputs[0];
        userInputs[0] = userInputs[2];
        userInputs[2] = h;

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your new array is");
        System.out.println();

        for(int i =0; i <10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(userInputs[i]);
        }



    }
}
```

Here is the code above after its ran:

[image: 1]

Comment: You could ask the user which two values they want to swap and get the result `System.out.println("Enter the first one to be swapped?");` then save the result `int firstToSwap = input.nextInt() -1;` and do the same for the second one, note that we use -1 because the first item in an array is at index 0 not at index 1, so the -1 takes care of the difference.

Comment: Dear @Master Oogie, Welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer (or any other one) has solved your problem, please, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation

Please, consider learning more about arrays.

For example, here is an article: [Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Please, see the excerpt from the article:

> ## Arrays
>
> An *array* is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed. You have seen an example of arrays already, in the `main` method of the "Hello World!" application. This section discusses arrays in greater detail.

Back to your guess:

> But to do this I'm assuming you need to name each individual box(es).

Each element (you seem to call it «box») in an array has a numerical index instead of a name.

Please, see the excerpt from the article:

> Each item in an array is called an element, and each element is accessed by its numerical index. As shown in the preceding illustration, numbering begins with 0. The 9th element, for example, would therefore be accessed at index 8.

## Draft implementation

The idea is to get the additional user input: the indices of the elements, whose values are to be swapped.

Replace this part:

```
System.out.println("Now im going to swap the first and third");

int h = userInputs[0];
userInputs[0] = userInputs[2];
userInputs[2] = h;
```

with this part:

```
System.out.println("Enter index of first element: ");
final int firstElementIndex = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter index of second element: ");
final int secondElementIndex = input.nextInt();

final int firstElement = userInputs[firstElementIndex];
userInputs[firstElementIndex] = userInputs[secondElementIndex];
userInputs[secondElementIndex] = firstElement;
```

Please, note that this is a draft implementation.
In particular, it does not have the array index validation for each entered array index.